# In Julia do I have to manually convert types of variables when doing mixed calculations?

Tags: julia

In Julia, if I have two variables,

```
i = 100::Int64
x = 33.333::Float64
```

If I want variable y which is

```
y = i*x
```

Now my question is, since it is a calculation mixed with Int64 and Float64, will it be slow?
I mean, like in Fortran, those stuff are compiled first then run, so during the compiling stage I guess the conversion has already be done.
But in Julia, since there is no compiling, basically it just run. I heard that if there are a lot of these conversions the code can be slow. Is it still true for the Julia nowadays?

If those type conversions things can slow down the Julia code, what should I do to prevent those type conversions and still make the code as fast as possible?

Thanks! I am sorry if the questions are very naïve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do a test:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime [100*33.33 for i in 1:100000000]
  218.062 ms (2 allocations: 762.94 MiB)

julia> @btime [100.0*33.33 for i in 1:100000000]
  218.326 ms (2 allocations: 762.94 MiB)
```

They're pretty much the same.

> in Julia, since there is no compiling

There is compiling in Julia, we can look at the machine code generated:

```
julia> code_llvm(+, (Int, Float64))
;  @ promotion.jl:321 within `+'
define double @"julia_+_807"(i64 signext %0, double %1) {
top:
; ┌ @ promotion.jl:292 within `promote'
; │┌ @ promotion.jl:269 within `_promote'
; ││┌ @ number.jl:7 within `convert'
; │││┌ @ float.jl:94 within `Float64'
      %2 = sitofp i64 %0 to double
; └└└└
;  @ promotion.jl:321 within `+' @ float.jl:326
  %3 = fadd double %2, %1
;  @ promotion.jl:321 within `+'
  ret double %3
}

julia> code_llvm(+, (Float64, Float64))
;  @ float.jl:326 within `+'
define double @"julia_+_796"(double %0, double %1) {
top:
  %2 = fadd double %0, %1
  ret double %2
}
```

So there are conversions going on at compile time.
BUT... the compiler handles these things really well, its nothing to worry about.

Comment: Great! Thanks! So, in general, if there are many mixed types involved in the calculation, do you think Julia can handle it well? Because I heard that if there are many type conversions involved, Julia may become slow. Is it still true? I feel that Julia nowadays should be able to handle those stuff pretty well.

Comment: In general, keeping the same type in hot loops is a good idea. That said the performance penalty, is only the cost of a conversion which is around 1 cycle, so it should be a pretty minor difference, if any.

Comment: The performance penalty comes when the compiler cannot figure out what the result type should be. This is known as a _type instability_, and is something one should avoid if performance is important.